# What is the faster way to printing how many times a char get repeated?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program to tell me how many times each letter of the English language gets repeated. I did manage to do it but im pretty sure there is a faster way.

```
with open('random.txt', 'r') as f:
f_contents = f.read()
print(f_contents.count('a'))
print(f_contents.count('b'))
print(f_contents.count('c'))
print(f_contents.count('d'))
print(f_contents.count('e'))
print(f_contents.count('g'))
print(f_contents.count('h'))
print(f_contents.count('i'))
print(f_contents.count('j'))
print(f_contents.count('k'))
print(f_contents.count('l'))
print(f_contents.count('m'))
print(f_contents.count('n'))
print(f_contents.count('o'))
print(f_contents.count('p'))
print(f_contents.count('q'))
print(f_contents.count('r'))
print(f_contents.count('s'))
print(f_contents.count('t'))
print(f_contents.count('u'))
print(f_contents.count('v'))
print(f_contents.count('w'))
print(f_contents.count('x'))
print(f_contents.count('y'))
print(f_contents.count('z'))
```

Comment: `collections.Counter` is your best bet here, but in any case even `for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:` would be better than typing each letter by hand

Comment: Hmm, you ask for "faster" and accept an answer that's a lot *slower*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Optionally, you can also use [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) to make it more DRY:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase

with open('random.txt', 'r') as f:
    f_contents = f.read()
    counts = Counter(f_contents)
    for c in ascii_lowercase:
        print(counts[c])
```

This collects all counts in a single iteration while repeated calls to `str.count` iterate the entire string every time.

Comment: and that last `print` can be `for letter, count in counts.items(): print(letter, count)`

Comment: That depends. If you are interested in zero counts as well as the OP's code suggests, you would have to iterate the entire domain.

Comment: That's true, good point

Comment: This looks like you're not aware of how absurdly fast `str.count` is.

Comment: @superbrain Eventually, for a large enough string and sufficiently large alphabet the linear algorithm will beat the quadratic one =) Also, you want to show sound generalizable approaches.

Comment: For a sufficiently large alphabet, yes. But this is explicitly about "each letter of the English language", and your suggestion is about *ten times slower*.

Comment: @superbrain How long a string did you use. I measure comparable times for 10**6 chars

Comment: @superbrain Sorry, I deleted the comment since it was obvious. From my measurement the `str.count` solution is still a factor of 2 faster on a 10MB file.

Comment: It was with `ascii_lowercase * 10**5`. What times did you get?

Comment: 4.5 and 5 respectively for a random string of lowercase ascii.

Comment: The problem with `Counter` is likely that you will have 10 million hash lookups on a 10 MB file, while with `str.count` you are looping the file/string 26 times, but you don't do any hashing (`str.count` is probably very low level C code). I wonder where the sweet spot is... It is still faster with 100e6 characters on my machine.

Comment: Ah, but which one is the faster one? :-) And what unit are 4.5 and 5 in?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Yeah, a while ago when I noticed that `str.count` went through over 4 billion characters per second on my 3 GHz CPU (i.e., more than one character per CPU cycle), I tracked down the code and I think it went to memchr and that used some SIMD instruction. *Very* low level where that speed comes from.

Comment: @superbrain For reference, this is the code I run for testing: https://pastebin.com/feC07AaS

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Here's [one from me](https://tio.run/##dZJBasMwEEX3OsXsKgUTEgKlFLzqpncIQTjK2FFrj4wkk/b0rqRxmpBSbWTpf70/w3j8jmdHu5fRz3Pr3QDRDmgj2GF0PoLHEZsoimJc36OJ1lG4ym9uooie9RC9pe4qNcFYq3t3QW@agGzxDZ3StljM2VmDQYhWG5c4FAPU8PS0/nCW5KLKB1AFn/V2s1o9KyVoGo7o05utECdsIZjzxR2Tqet6qV4FpGVyiZm71CpvYaoYPMbJE@zZuDcHaJ0HA5YeezhwyrsjutJ7jImZ8Y/93qNvkeuSIvmZKkn8neMWWIppJzIZet9QVYKFwK8xTSGJxbTfHKQSmZOPmVKuuboxDSTKfCEV1DXw06pY1lpTM6DWSrBNiYLRmZHm1KHcLU3@Q88r1zGkYfF/UqIq4LHUvCn1a@acv/k3Tc3zDw). Randomness seems to shrink the speed difference, and on TIO and my PC the difference is smaller than on repl.it.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Oh drat, we've all been doing it wrong, as the OP wants to skip the letter `'f'`. But it'll make the `str.count` method factor 1.04 faster, woohoo!11!!

Comment: @superbrain I think the missing `'f'` is an obvious mistake due to how the code is written (I read your comment with some witty irony, right?). And as you point it, it will speed up "your" method. The smaller the alphabet, the better, avoiding the issues of quadratic runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Create a list with all the letters (or find one online in a library) and iterate.

```
 letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] # and so on...
 # or use this:
 letters = string.ascii_lowercase # as Cory Kramer pointed out
 for letter in letters:
     print(f_contents.count(letter))
```

Comment: No need for `letters` as `string.ascii_lowercase` already contains that sequence

Comment: didn't know about that, will add it to the answer. The main point is to use a loop though